# Compiler error - Returning an char array

Tags: c

I just coded this function.
A few minutes ago it still works, but now it doesn't.

Here the function:

```
char* listen(){
    static char ieingabe[256];
    scanf("%s", ieingabe);
    return ieingabe;
}
```

The compiler gives me this error:

> conflicting types for 'listen'

Comment: "A few minutes ago it still works, but now it doesn't" - sounds like you added in some code since then, check it!

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Look at line numbers supplied with the error message. The errror is at one of those lines.

Comment: The code you have posted is OK.  You must have written a different declaration of `listen` earlier; or attempted to call the function without a declaration in scope.

Comment: Let me guess: You don't have a prototype for your `listen()` and it conflicts with the implicit one (C89) declared by the compiler. Or you included some other code since that has a `listen()` declared (for exmple, `<sys/socket.h>` which has a function `listen()`).

Comment: Consider using a more modern compiler; since 1999 you should get a different error message.

Answer (score 2):

You probably called `listen` lexically before the definition, so the call let it default to `int listen()`. Add this line at the top of the file (after all includes):

```
char *listen(void);
```

Or better, create an include (`.h`) file for this.

Comment: @M.M agreed, changed my answer

Comment: Thank you. After I did this, it works fine!